# python numpy, sort a matrix by row and column

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.6

I would like to use numpy to create a square matrix where rows other than the first are sorted by the contents of the first row. For example:

```
import numpy as np
a = array([['','z','b','d'],
           ['b','2','5','7'],
           ['d','0','1','3'],
           ['z','3','9','2']])
```

return:

```
[['','z','b','d']
 ['z','3','9','2']
 ['b','2','5','7']
 ['d','0','1','3']]
```

Comment: So you are looking to sort lexicographically by the 1st column?

Comment: @Bitwise: the sort should be based on the contents of the first row. I've revised the question's text and example to be more clear.

Comment: Your example seems confusing because the result is not simply a reorder of the rows (ie, the row starting with 'z' is `['z','3','9','2']` but in your return it is `['z','0','1','3']`)

Comment: Not only did it seem confusing, it was confusing - when I renamed rows to clarify the goal, I entered the wrong values to return, as you point out. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way, assuming that what you want is indeed a sort of the rows based on first row:

```
>>> a[[list(a[:, 0]).index(i) for i in a[0]]]
array([['', 'z', 'b', 'd'],
       ['z', '3', '9', '2'],
       ['b', '2', '5', '7'],
       ['d', '0', '1', '3']], 
       dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear why you want to have this data in a numpy array, when a dictionary would probably be more appropriate. I assume you want to do some calculations on the data, for which you probably don't want a string dtype.

In your example you want to sort from a key in the first row, presumably strings. If you want to access the array in a 'square' form (e.g. slices like `a[:, 2]`), this will mean all the elements will be converted to strings. Structured arrays will allow you do do a better sorting, but at the expense of having to do slices like `a[:][2]`. Here's an example with a structured array that puts your data into an array with a string dtype `'names'`, and the values as integers in a dtype `'values'`. You can do the sorting by the strings in `'names'`:

```
a = np.array([('b', [2, 5, 7]),
              ('d', [0, 1, 3]), 
              ('z', [3, 9, 2])],
              dtype=[('names', 'S1'),
                     ('values', '3int')])
```

You can access the names and the values records separately:

```
>>> a['names']
array(['b', 'd', 'z'], 
      dtype='|S5')

>>> a['values']
array([[2, 5, 7],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [3, 9, 2]])
```

And you can sort the values array based on a lexicographic sort of the names:

```
>>> a['values'][np.argsort(a['names'])]
array([[2, 5, 7],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [3, 9, 2]])
```

Or just sort the array using another order of the names:

```
>>> a['values'][np.argsort(['z', 'b', 'd'])]
array([[0, 1, 3],
       [3, 9, 2],
       [2, 5, 7]])
```

Comment: My reading of the question suggests that the sort order is determined by the contents of row 0, whereas your code appears to sort rows lexicographically based on column 0.

Comment: @NPE That is in fact the case.

Comment: True, I just expanded on the answer to address the question. It is unclear from the question why numpy arrays are necessary.